# Pad a file with zeros

Tags: code-golf, file-system

Your task today will be to take an existing file and append zeros to it until it reaches a certain size.

You must write a program or function which takes the name of a file in the current directory `f` and a number of bytes `b`. While maintaining the original content of `f`, you must write zeroes ***(null bytes, not ascii 0s)*** to the end so that its new size is `b` bytes.

You may assume that `f` only has alphanumeric ascii in its name, that you have full permissions over it, that it initially is not larger than `b`, but may be as large as `b`, and that there is infinite free disk space.

You may not assume `f` is nonempty, or that it does not already contain null bytes.

Other existing files should not be modified and new files should not exist after execution ends.

### Test Cases

```
Contents of f | b  | Resulting contents of f
12345         | 10 | 1234500000
0             | 3  | 000
[empty]       | 2  | 00
[empty]       | 0  | [empty]
123           | 3  | 123
```

Comment: @totallyhuman *it initially is not larget than `b`*

Comment: Can we take the contents of the file as input and output the modified contents?

Comment: May we use libraries?

Comment: @Phoenix The problem is that Dennis put the library in a far away folder (not my choice). Can I count as if it was available in the search path?

Comment: Can we assume the file will not already contain null bytes?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Bash + coreutils, 13

```bash
truncate -s$@
```

Input from the command-line - the first parameter is the file size and the second is the filename.

From `man truncate`:

> If a FILE is shorter, it is extended and the extended part (hole) reads as zero bytes.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifmpyRr6DklJqWX5RqpcRVUJSZV5KmYGhkbGKqYAeh9UoqSrgqKlKQeMWpJQq6ugqGBgix/yVFpXnJiSWpCrrFKg5gc7kghjumlaQWAc1GMeI/AA).

Comment: Can truncate extend too?

Comment: A man who knows his mans in a manly man indeed.

Comment: I wonder if it works on a FAT partition, where the `truncate` syscall fails.

Comment: My implementation of the same idea would have been `dd bs=1 of=$1 seek=$2<&-` (which prints an error message that can be ignored). Yours is far shorter. Nice.

Comment: @hvd yep I figured dd could probably do this

Answer (score 4):

## Groovy, <s>54</s> <s>47</s> <s>43</s> 41 bytes

```
{a,b->(c=new File(a))<<'\0'*(b-c.size())}
```

*-6 thanks to manatwork's idea of removing the loop; that was my original idea, don't know why I thought it wouldn't work and opted for a loop... It definitely works, just tested it.*

## Ungolfed:

```
{
    a,b->                    // Two inputs: a is the File name, b is the desired size.
    File c = new File(a)     // Make and store the file.
    c << '\0'*(b-c.size())   // Append the difference between b and c.size() in nullbytes.
}
                             // Usually a close would be required, but, in Groovy,
                             // because private data isn't so protected, if a File
                             // Object goes out of scope, the attached Stream is 
                             // automatically flushed to disk.
```

Comment: Wouldn't be shorter loopless? `{a,b->c=new File(a);c<<('\0'*(b-c.size()))}`

Comment: @manatwork yeah! And it can actually be even better than that.

Comment: @manatwork nevermind, same bytecount for `(c=new File(a))` due to required parenthesis.

Comment: No idea why I put parenthesis around the entire value to append. Not needed.

Comment: @manatwork Groovy is pretty temperamental about the parenthesis, can't blame you haha.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>33</s> 17 bytes

```apl
⎕⎕NRESIZE⍞⎕NTIE¯1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKPdtaIkNS/l/6O@qUDkF@Qa7Bnl@qh3HogT4ul6aL0hSNF/BTDQeNTVpJ6RmpOTr1CeX5SToq4JUhYQGqJeklpcoldSUaLOBVGp7p@TolCcWZVqpa5jBFLk6efmj6EKYjcXTJjLyACm3S@1nLB2dafKklSFssSc0tRioEKgulDnYAWINxxdFIBuV7AwAFNADAA)

Comment: What's `∇Extend`?

Comment: @Phoenix Just the name of the program so it can be called. [Here is a version without naming the program.](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/@v8airST0jNScnX6E8vygnRV3zUd9Uv4DQEPWS1OISvZKKEnUuoMijtgnq/jkpCsWZValW6jpGIEWefm7@CFX/D603VLAwBkk4BgS4@rk86l1h8Kh3C5ACiumCxIM9o1wf9c4DMUM8XYHq/0NN9kstx2cyjMVlZAAA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>59</s> <s>57</s> 54 bytes

<sup>-5 bytes thanks to chepner</sup>

```python
def g(n,b):f=open(n,'a');f.write('\0'*b);f.truncate(b)
```

Comment: @totallyhuman `\x00` is a null byte.

Comment: @totallyhuman no, it is more like a flag thing (to disallow interactino with closed files)

Comment: @Rod I love interactino! Best child-friendly interactive game ever

Comment: You can use `\0` in place of `\x00`.

Comment: You can save another three bytes by overextending, then truncating: `def g(n,b):f=open(n,'a');f.write('\0'*b);f.truncate(b)`.

Comment: Can you do `f=open(n,'a').write('\0'*b)`?

Comment: @ComradeSparklePony yeah, but it would return `None`

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 66 bytes

```php
for($p=fopen($f=$argv[1],a);filesize($f)<$argv[2];)fputs($p,"\0");
```

Takes input from command line arguments; run with `-nr`.

---

These 55 bytes might, but most probably will not, work:

```php
fseek($p=fopen($argv[1],"w+"),$argv[2]);fputs($p,"\0");
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java (Oracle JRE), 55 bytes

```
f->b->new java.io.RandomAccessFile(f,"rw").setLength(b)
```

The spec of `setLength(int)` says that the appended bytes are undefined, but practically the Oracle JRE appends only the `0` byte (that's why I specified it).

The resource is automatically closed by the JVM so we don't need to do it ourself.

### Test

```
public class Pcg125661 {
  interface F {
    B f(String f);
  }
  interface B {
    void b(int b) throws java.io.IOException;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
    F a = f->b->new java.io.RandomAccessFile(f,"rw").setLength(b);
    a.f("a").b(100);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## AHK, 48 bytes

```
FileGetSize,s,%1%
2-=s
Loop,%2%
FileAppend,0,%1%
```

`1` and `2` are the first two parameters in an AHK script.
`FileGetSize` works in bytes by default.
It's not exciting, but it's simple: Get the size, subtract it from the desired size, and add that many zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 40 bytes

```
{$_=$^a.IO;.open(:a).put("\0"x($^b-.s))}
```

`$^a` and `$^b` are the parameters to the function--the file name and the length, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 68 bytes

```python
def g(f,b):
 with open(f,'r+')as c:c.write('\x00'*(b-len(c.read())))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5BDsIgEEX3nILdMIoNrbrpWdxQyrQkTUuQBD09TtI0Rv9mNv/N@/Gd523tagl5llv0qwICLaEASvuU1AvJoaakkL2Ctrve7oB19CQnRXpALnxZ0pDOgAy63h3M42UMnNRwWbjhmuTtqJBTp93VGhTi359@/DGFNfOKneUTF@uO19w2POkD) (When printing the file's content, the code replaces null bytes with ASCII 0's for visibility.)

Comment: I think this writes ASCII zeroes and not null bytes

Comment: Ah... the word zeroes was misleading...

Comment: Well, it does say in large letters in the challenge itself.

Comment: Can you use a literal \x00 in the string (not an escape sequence)?

Comment: You can't use a literal null byte, but `\0` is shorter.

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell, 69 bytes

```powershell
param($f,$s)@(gc $f -en by)+,[byte]0*($s-(gi $f).length)|sc $f -en by
#     ^ filename
#        ^desired size
#                 ^ get content as byte stream
#           ^force it to an array even if there's 0 or 1 byte
#                          ^append a byte array of nulls..
#                                       ^..desired size - file size
#                            write to file with -encoding byte ^
```

`$f` for the file, `$s` for the destination size, save as .ps1 and run

```powershell
.\Add-NullBytesToFile.ps1 .\test.txt 10
```

---

It's a shell, so there should be a really small loop adding 1 byte with `>>` output redirection and append, right? Well, no, because `>>` only outputs UCS2-LE multibyte encoding so there's no way to add a single byte to a file with it .. unless you're using PSv5.1 and you can change that but that makes it too long to be competitive:

```powershell
$PSDefaultParameterValues['Out-File:Encoding']='utf8';while((gi $f).length-lt$c){[byte]0>>$f}
```

Maybe there's a .Net Framework approach? There should be, but I can't make it actually write any bytes, or error. But it's longer anyway:

```powershell
param($f,$s)[io.file]::WriteAllBytes($f,[byte[]](,0)*($c-(gi $f).length), $True)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica 50 Bytes

Import/Export

```
Export[#,Import[#,c="Byte"]~Join~Table[0,{#2}],c]&
```

Usage

```
%["test1", 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, 56 bytes

```
fseek(f,0,2);int i;for(;ftell(f)<b;)putc(0,f);fclose(f);
```

The program finds the file's size, and how many bytes to append. The file then adds `fs - b` extra bytes to the end.

Comment: Welcom to PPCG! This is a [tag:code-golf] challenge, so your objective is to make your program as small as possible. You should start by removing unnecesary whitespace.

Comment: In addition, your program seems to assume that the inputs are already stored in the values `f` and `b`, which isn't allowed. You *must* include i/o into your program, which can be from `ARGV`, console input, or arguments to a function.

Comment: Thank you, I thought that the variables were assumed to be set already. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

## q, 29 bytes

Function which takes file name in format `:/foo/bar.baz` and length as an integer.

```
{hopen[x](0|y-hcount x)#0x00}
```

Example:

```
{hopen[x](0|y-hcount x)#0x00}[`:test.txt;100]
```

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 90 bytes

```c#
using System.IO;s=>n=>File.AppendAllText(s,new string('\0',(int)new FileInfo(s).Length-n))
```